# How do I add addEventListener to change the color of each svg in a list when clicked?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
<ul id='modes' class='flex-row-wrap'>
      <li class="list-btn"><a href="#">Btn1</a>
        <i class="favorite">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg- 
          inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 
           512">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7- 
            20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 
            12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
          </svg>
        </i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-btn"><a href="#">Button Text here is very long 2</a>
        <i class="favorite">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg- 
          inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 
           512">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7- 
            20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 
            12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
          </svg>
        </i>
      </li>
```

//Javascript Code

```
 function changeColor(event)  {
        if (event.target.tagName === 'svg'){
            event.target.color = "#eb3b67";
            console.log('ColorChanged!');
            console.log(event.target)
        }
    }
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.favorite').forEach(item =>{
        item.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
    })
```

I'm trying to change the color of each svg when clicked and back to default when clicked again but can't seem to target the svg.

Comment: `event.target` is probably not the `svg` but the `path` element inside it? What does the `console.log(event.target)` print?

Comment: It doesn't print anything.

Comment: Move the `console.log` call outside the `if` statement.

Comment: Did that, still blank.

Comment: Hi, that is because event.target.tagName not always is svg, you need to change the way you check the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually clicking on a `path` not the svg itself, so perhaps use this and `parentElement` to set the color:

```js
function changeColor(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'path') {
    event.target.parentElement.setAttribute("color","#eb3b67");
    console.log('ColorChanged!');
    //console.log(event.target)
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.favorite').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
})
```

```html
<ul id='modes' class='flex-row-wrap'>
  <li class="list-btn"><a href="#">Btn1</a>
    <i class="favorite">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg- 
          inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 
           512">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7- 
            20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 
            12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
          </svg>
        </i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-btn"><a href="#">Button Text here is very long 2</a>
    <i class="favorite">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg- 
          inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 
           512">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7- 
            20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 
            12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
          </svg>
        </i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've made adjustments but still no changes. Also, my console prints nothing when svg is clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) (`<i class="favorite">`) to get the `svg` element.  The currentTarget always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `Event.target`, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

```js
const COLOR = "rgb(235, 59, 103)";

function changeColor(event) {
  const svg = event.currentTarget.firstElementChild; //--> svg element
  const color = svg.style.color === COLOR ? "initial" : COLOR;
  svg.style.color = color;
}

document.querySelectorAll(".favorite").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
});
```

```html
<ul id='modes' class='flex-row-wrap'>
  <li class="list-btn"><a href="#">Btn1</a>
    <i class="favorite">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg- 
          inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 
           512">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7- 
            20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 
            12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
          </svg>
        </i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-btn"><a href="#">Button Text here is very long 2</a>
    <i class="favorite">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" class="svg- 
          inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 
           512">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7- 
            20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 
            12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path>
          </svg>
        </i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, in the 20 odd years ive been writing JS I never picked up on the fact that currentTarget differed from target. Learn something new every day

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, also you can use firstChild instead of querySelector

Comment: Yes, I think that firstElementChild will do the job